# Kubernetes probe without blocking requests to POD on failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Given:

1. My application (call it `root`) is considered 'ready' when certain number of other PODs connects to it.
2. I would like to rely on the fact the `root` application is 'ready' because transition from POD creation to 'readiness' takes considerable amount of time.

Thus I wanted to create `readinessProbe`, but as it initially fails (waiting for my other PODs to connect), the kubelet blocks all of the requests coming to that `root` POD making it impossible to fulfill my 'ready' condition.

I managed to handle the situation by adding `readinessProbe` to all other PODs and thus considering the `root` POD ready when all other PODs are ready.

Question:
Is it possible to inform kubernetes that even though the `readinessProbe` fails, the service for that `root` POD should still accept traffic (from small group of pods at least)?
And more broadly speaking: is it possible to have `readinessProbe` on `kind: Deployment` level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that, by design service that is not ready won't receive traffic.

If you elaborate on your design I can try and give you more tips but generally, looks like you might want your `root` to connect to the other pods and not the other way around.